# Why does operator== work for statically initialized char*?

Tags: c++, string-comparison

When creating a char array like:

```
char c_array1[] = { "str1" };
char c_array2[] = { "str1" };
char* cp_array1 = c_array1;
char* cp_array2 = c_array2;
if(cp_array1 == cp_array2) { // char* cannot be compared with char*
```

The comparison does fail. But with statically initialized char*:

```
char* cp_array1 = "str1";
char* cp_array2 = "str1";
if(cp_array1 == cp_array2) { // char* can be compared with char*
```

It works.
Why does the operator== behave differently for the same type of parameters in this case?

Comment: `char* cannot be compared with char*` - yes it can

Comment: Which compiler did you use? It works fine with clang and gcc https://godbolt.org/z/84hEefzn7

Comment: Works on MSVC. Looks like your compiler is trying to protect you from doing something stupid

Comment: I was using https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Comment: They both "work", in the sense of being syntactically valid expressions that give a result. They produce *different* results in your examples (with your compiler).  In the first example, `c_array1` and `c_array2` are distinct arrays, so pointers to their first element compare as not-equal.  In the second example, the pointers *may* compare equal, because they point at the same string literal (result of the comparison is unspecified). String literals have static storage duration, and modifying them involves undefined behaviour, so the compiler is allowed (not required) to merge them into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*But with statically initialized char* It works*" - It ***may*** work - if the compiler optimized your code to store only one `str1` (which it is allowed to do).

You are comparing pointers - not the strings they point at.

If you want to compare the strings, use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp):

```
if(std::strcmp(cp_array1, cp_array2)) {
    // not equal
} else {
    // equal
}
```

The strings are `const` though, so it should be `const char* cp_array1 = "str1";` and `const char* cp_array2 = "str1";`

Comment: Ah ok, so the compiler optimization makes both string literals to be the Same. That makes sense.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it may even store overlapping strings in the same way so that `const char* a = "foobar";` and `const char* b = "bar";` could result in `a + 3 == b`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  // char* cannot be compared with char*
> ```

`char*` can be compared with `char*`

> The comparison does fail

There is no reason why the program would fail to compare the pointers. The shown program is well-formed if the missing parts are added. The pointers will compare unequal because they point to different objects.

> ```
> char* cp_array1 = "str1";
> char* cp_array2 = "str1";
> ```

This program is ill-formed. A string literal is not convertible to non-const `char*` (since C++11).

If you fix that, then the pointers may compare equal or they might not, depending on whether the compiler used the same array for the separate string literals (typically, compilers do use the same array at least when they occur in the same translation unit).

Comment: With
const char* cp_array1 = "str1";
    const char* cp_array2 = "str1";
I get the same results.

Comment: @Mestkon Because string literal doesn't have an implicit conversion to pointer to non-const char.